# How can I modify inline citation style in Word 2015 for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, citations, bibliography

My professor insists that we use Chicago style of bibliography, but also wants inline citations to be in this format (Author, Year). However, the default Chicago style is (Author Year).

Is there a way to fix this?